# How is a type-erased generic wrapper implemented?

Tags: swift, generics

I need to implement a type-erasing wrapper for my own structure, very similar to `SequenceOf`, `GeneratorOf`, etc. So I started by trying to just re-implement the standard `SequenceOf` myself.

I just copied & pasteed the the declaration for `SequenceOf`, renamed it to `MySequenceOf`, and filled in some stubs to get:

```
/// A type-erased sequence.
///
/// Forwards operations to an arbitrary underlying sequence with the
/// same `Element` type, hiding the specifics of the underlying
/// sequence type.
///
/// See also: `GeneratorOf<T>`.
struct MySequenceOf<T> : SequenceType {

    /// Construct an instance whose `generate()` method forwards to
    /// `makeUnderlyingGenerator`
    init<G : GeneratorType where T == T>(_ makeUnderlyingGenerator: () -> G) {
        fatalError("implement me")
    }

    /// Construct an instance whose `generate()` method forwards to
    /// that of `base`.
    init<S : SequenceType where T == T>(_ base: S) {
        fatalError("implement me")
    }

    /// Return a *generator* over the elements of this *sequence*.
    ///
    /// Complexity: O(1)
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> {
        fatalError("implement me")
    }
}
```

I get the compiler error: "*Neither type in same-type refers to a generic parameter or associated type*". So I assume that the Xcode-generated declaration of `SequenceOf`'s "`where T == T`" constraint really means "`where G.Element == T`", which gives me the following compilable struct:

```
struct MySequenceOf<T> : SequenceType {

    init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == T>(_ makeUnderlyingGenerator: () -> G) {
        fatalError("implement me")
    }

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> {
        fatalError("implement me")
    }
}
```

So now, easy enough, I just need to hang on to `makeUnderlyingGenerator` from the initializer and invoke it from `generate()`:

```
struct MySequenceOf<T> : SequenceType {
    let maker: ()->GeneratorOf<T>

    init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == T>(_ makeUnderlyingGenerator: () -> G) {
        self.maker = { return makeUnderlyingGenerator() }
    }

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> {
        return self.maker()
    }
}
```

but that gives me the error: "*'G' is not convertible to 'GeneratorOf'*"

It **does** compiles if I force a cast:

```
struct MySequenceOf<T> : SequenceType {
    let maker: ()->GeneratorOf<T>

    init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == T>(_ makeUnderlyingGenerator: () -> G) {
        self.maker = { return makeUnderlyingGenerator() as GeneratorOf<T> }
    }

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> {
        return self.maker()
    }
}
```

But then it crashes at runtime from the dynamic cast.

So how can type-erasure like this be implemented? It must be possible, because the Swift standard library does it a bunch (SequenceOf, GeneratorOf, SinkOf).

Comment: Try defining the Generator typealias for your type.

Comment: "So I assume that the Xcode-generated declaration of SequenceOf's "where T == T" constraint really means "where G.Element == T"" Yes, it's a well-known bug in the way the declaration is displayed in Xcode. You can't actually say `where T == T`, and the Swift header doesn't actually say it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
struct MySequenceOf<T> : SequenceType {
    private let _generate:() -> MyGeneratorOf<T>

    init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == T>(_ makeUnderlyingGenerator: () -> G) {
        _generate = { MyGeneratorOf(makeUnderlyingGenerator()) }
    }

    init<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(_ base: S) {
        _generate = { MyGeneratorOf(base.generate()) }
    }

    func generate() -> MyGeneratorOf<T> {
        return _generate()
    }
}

struct MyGeneratorOf<T> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {

    private let _next:() -> T?

    init(_ nextElement: () -> T?) {
        _next = nextElement
    }

    init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == T>(var _ base: G) {
        _next = { base.next() }
    }

    mutating func next() -> T? {
        return _next()
    }

    func generate() -> MyGeneratorOf<T> {
        return self
    }
}
```

The **basic** strategy of implementing `ProtocolOf<T>` is, like this:

```
protocol ProtocolType {
    typealias Value
    func methodA() -> Value
    func methodB(arg:Value) -> Bool
}

struct ProtocolOf<T>:ProtocolType {
    private let _methodA: () -> T
    private let _methodB: (T) -> Bool

    init<B:ProtocolType where B.Value == T>(_ base:B) {
        _methodA = { base.methodA() }
        _methodB = { base.methodB($0) }
    }

    func methodA() -> T { return _methodA() }
    func methodB(arg:T) -> Bool { return _methodB(arg) }
}
```

---

**Added** to answering @MartinR in comment.

> Is there a special reason that _generate is a closure and not the generator itself?

First of all, I think, It's a matter of specification or semantics.

Needless to say, the difference is "when to create the generator".

Consider this code:

```
class Foo:SequenceType {
    var vals:[Int] = [1,2,3]
    func generate() -> Array<Int>.Generator {
        return vals.generate()
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
let seq = MySequenceOf(foo)
foo.vals = [4,5,6]
let result = Array(seq)
```

The problem is: `result` should be `[1,2,3]` or `[4,5,6]`? My `MySequenceOf` and built-in `SequenceOf` results the latter. I just matched the behaviors with built-in one.

Comment: I took me quite a while to figure out my answer, but I must admit that yours looks neater. Is there a special reason that `_generate` is a closure and not the generator itself (as in my code)?

Comment: @MartinR Added to the answer. And as a side-note, see this:  https://github.com/andelf/Defines-Swift/blob/14a3c623278344cb433b80fb4197f1a64f52d5ad/Swift.swift#L3837

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample implementation of `MySequenceOf` which seems to work:

```
struct MySequenceOf<T> : SequenceType {

    let myGenerator : GeneratorOf<T>

    init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == T>(_ makeUnderlyingGenerator: () -> G) {
        self.myGenerator = GeneratorOf( makeUnderlyingGenerator() )
    }

    init<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(_ base: S) {
        self.myGenerator = GeneratorOf( base.generate() )
    }

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> {
        return myGenerator
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let seq = MySequenceOf {
    _ -> GeneratorOf<Int> in
    var i = 0
    return GeneratorOf {
        i < 5 ? ++i : nil
    }
}
for i in seq  { println(i) }
```

You can also replace `GeneratorOf` from the Swift library by the following
`MyGeneratorOf`:

```
struct MyGeneratorOf<T> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {

    var nextFunc : () -> T?

    init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == T>(_ base: G) {
        self.nextFunc = {
            () -> T? in
            var generator = base
            return generator.next()
        }
    }

    init(_ nextElement: () -> T?) {
        self.nextFunc = nextElement
    }

    mutating func next() -> T? {
        return nextFunc()
    }

    // Returns a copy of itself.
    func generate() -> MyGeneratorOf<T> {
        return MyGeneratorOf(nextFunc)
    }

}
```

So (as far as I understand it, and I am far from understanding all the generic sequence
and generator stuff) the "trick" is that the `next()` method of the
generator is a closure which captures the given generator and therefore can
forward the `next()` call. A cast is not necessary.