# How to implement CollectionOf in Swift

Tags: generics, swift

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832498/how-is-a-type-erased-generic-wrapper-implemented), I'm trying to implement an equivalent for `CollectionType` called `CollectionOf`, but I'm having trouble with one of the constraints:

```
struct CollectionOf<T, Index: ForwardIndexType>: CollectionType {
    init<C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == T, C.Index == Index>(_ collection: C) {
        // etc.
    }
    // etc.
}
```

This does not compile. Let's ignore the fact that I haven't implemented the members of `CollectionType` yet. I'll get to that. The problem I face is that the compiler doesn't like my `init`. It complains, "Same-type constraint Index does not conform to required protocol ForwardIndexType." Clearly it does.

Perhaps we have a compiler bug. Perhaps my syntax is wrong. Whatever the case, how can I implement `CollectionOf`?

## EDIT

Here is a working implementation. Due to the problem noted above, it suffers from the serious flaw that the `Index typealias` of `CollectionType` is not constrained to be same as that of the wrapped `CollectionType`. This means I am forced to cast, which could in theory cause a problem at runtime rather than at compilation time, which defeats the purpose of static typing.

```
struct CollectionOf<T, I: ForwardIndexType>: CollectionType {
    private let _generate: () -> GeneratorOf<T>
    private let _startIndex: () -> I
    private let _endIndex: () -> I
    private let _subscript: (I) -> T

    init<C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == T>(_ collection: C) {
        _generate = { GeneratorOf(collection.generate()) }
        _startIndex = { collection.startIndex as I }
        _endIndex = { collection.endIndex as I }
        _subscript = { i in collection[i as C.Index] }
    }

    var startIndex: I {
        return _startIndex()
    }

    var endIndex: I {
        return _endIndex()
    }

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> {
        return _generate()
    }

    subscript (i: I) -> T {
        return _subscript(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason, it looks like the compiler isn't looking inside `CollectionType` to find that its index is already a `ForwardIndex`. If you add `C.Index: ForwardIndexType` to the where clause of your generic constraint, the compiler stops bugging you.

---

Here's a way to implement `CollectionOf<T>` with an index that is always an `Int`. The one downside here is that some operations, namely finding `endIndex` and subscripting, may be *O*(*N*) instead of *O*(1). If the collection passed in has an index of type `Int`, all operations will be *O*(1).

```
struct CollectionOf<T>: CollectionType {
    typealias Index = Int

    private let _generate: () -> GeneratorOf<T>
    private let _subscript: (Int) -> T
    private let _endIndex: () -> Int

    init<C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == T>(_ collection: C) {
        _generate = { GeneratorOf(collection.generate()) }
        _subscript = {
            (i: Int) in
            if C.Index.self is Int.Type {
                return collection[((collection.startIndex as Int) + i) as C.Index]
            } else {
                let index = reduce(0..<i, collection.startIndex) { $0.0.successor() }
                return collection[index]
            }
        }
        _endIndex = {
            if C.Index.Distance.self is Int.Type {
                return distance(collection.startIndex, collection.endIndex) as Int
            } else {
                return reduce(collection.startIndex..<collection.endIndex, 0) { $0.0 + 1 }
            }
        }
    }

    var startIndex: Int {
        return 0
    }

    var endIndex: Int {
        return _endIndex()
    }

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> {
        return _generate()
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> T {
        return _subscript(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example? When I try that, the compiler still complains about the same-type constraint, i.e., `init<C: CollectionType where C.Index: ForwardIndexType, C.Generator.Element == T, C.Index == Index>` still does not compile.

Comment: That code worked for me. Have you implemented the rest of CollectionType? I've found the compiler gives funny error messages when protocols aren't fully conformed to.

Comment: No dice. If you look at the code I posted above in my edit, and change the signature of `init` as specified in my comment above, it does not compile. Same error.

Comment: Actually, since I've called my type parameter `I`, you would actually have to say `init<C: CollectionType where C.Index: ForwardIndexType, C.Generator.Element == T, C.Index == I>`, but that's a minor detail.

Comment: Added an implementation that fully hides the original collection type, with a trade-off. What do you think?

Comment: That is really clever. Effectively, if `CollectionType.Index` isn't an Int, you're just using `successor()` to get to the equivalent `Index` value for the non-Int type. Not great for very large collections, but probably the best we can do until Swift's slightly broken generics system is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `CollectionType.Index.Distance` as `CollectionOf<T>.Index` makes the things simpler:

```
struct CollectionOf<T>:CollectionType {
    private let _generate: () -> GeneratorOf<T>
    private let _endIndex: () -> Int
    private let _subscript: (Int) -> T

    init<C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == T, C.Index.Distance == Int>(_ base: C) {
        _generate = { GeneratorOf(base.generate()) }
        _endIndex = { distance(base.startIndex, base.endIndex) }
        _subscript = { base[advance(base.startIndex, $0)] }
    }

    var startIndex: Int { return 0 }
    var endIndex: Int { return _endIndex() }
    subscript (i: Int) -> T { return _subscript(i) }
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> { return _generate() }
}
```

This constraints `C.Index.Distance == Int`, but as far as I know, all `Index.Distance` of builtin `CollectionType` is `Int`. so there is no practical defect here.

If you do want to accept all `CollectionType`, use `IntMax`:

```
struct CollectionOf<T>:CollectionType {
    private let _generate: () -> GeneratorOf<T>
    private let _endIndex: () -> IntMax
    private let _subscript: (IntMax) -> T

    init<C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == T>(_ base: C) {
        _generate = { GeneratorOf(base.generate()) }
        _endIndex = { distance(base.startIndex, base.endIndex).toIntMax() }
        _subscript = { base[advance(base.startIndex, C.Index.Distance($0))] }
    }

    var startIndex: IntMax { return 0 }
    var endIndex: IntMax { return _endIndex() }
    subscript (i: IntMax) -> T { return _subscript(i) }
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> { return _generate() }
}
```

This works because `CollectionType.Index.Distance` is `_SignedIntegerType` and `_SignedIntegerType` has `toIntMax()` and `init(_: IntMax)`

Comment: I see, `IntMax` is an alias for `Int64`. At the moment, all `ForwardIndexType`s in the standard library are integers of one kind or another, but is it conceivable to have an index that is *not* an integer? (Ultimately any such index would have to be mappable onto an integer, I assume.)

Comment: Maybe you are confusing with `Index` and `Index.Distance`. "index" is *not* always integer(e.g. `String.Index`), but "distance of index" is guaranteed to be "signed integer", at least in Swift 1.1.

Comment: What I'm talking about is the `Index` associated type of the `CollectionType`, which is constrained to conform to the `ForwardIndexType` protocol. Nothing says it must be an integer as far as I know, though it's hard to imagine what else it would be.

Comment: Yes, you are right `ForwardIndexType` is not integer, it should be considered as **opaque** type. But `ForwardIndexType` conforms `_ForwardIndexType`, and associated `_FowardIndexType.Distance` conforms `_SignedIntegerType`. see `protocol _ForwardIndexType` definition. The basic idea of my answer is this can be used as `Index` of `CollectionOf<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

This answer is still technically correct. Nate Cook has a workaround so clever I decided to mark it correct.

## Original Answer

After a lot of searching, it turns out that as of this writing, I believe it is not possible to create a *generalized* typesafe `CollectionOf`. The problem can be boiled down thus:

```
protocol AwesomeType {
    typealias Crazy: ForwardIndexType
}

struct AwesomeOf<C: ForwardIndexType> {
    init<A: AwesomeType where A.Crazy == C>(_ awesome: A) {
    }
}
```

What we are trying to tell the compiler in our initializer is that the associated type `Crazy` (which must conform to the `ForwardIndexType` protocol) is exactly equivalent to our class-level generic type parameter `C`, which has been declared to conform to `ForwardIndexType` as needed.

Unfortunately this just doesn't work. Inside of a method-level generic constraint, the compiler treats class-level generic parameters as if they were unconstrained, thus producing the error.

I've done lots of testing and found nothing that contradicts this assumption. If anyone knows a way around this, I'd love to know.

This means that the only way to do a typesafe (but not generalized) `CollectionOf` is unfortunately to leak type information, as follows:

```
class CollectionOf<C: CollectionType>: CollectionType {
    init(_ collection: C) {
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it is not general enough. It leaks the type of the underlying collection, e.g., instead of `CollectionOf<Int, Int>` we must say `CollectionOf<Array<Int>>`. This is a real shame and I hope it is fixed in a future release of Swift.