# What enables SwiftUI's DSL?

Tags: swift, swiftui

It seems like Apple's new `SwiftUI` framework uses a **new kind of syntax** that effectively builds a tuple, but has another syntax:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Hello, World") // No comma, no separator ?!
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

**Trying to tackle down what this syntax really is**, I found out that the `VStack` initializer used here takes a closure of the type `() -> Content`
as the second parameter, where `Content` is a generic param conforming to `View` that is inferred via the closure. To find out what type `Content` is inferred to, I changed the code slightly, maintaining its functionality:

```
var body: some View {
    let test = VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Hello, World")
        Text("Hello World!")
    }

    return test
}
```

With this, `test` reveals itself to be of type `VStack<TupleView<(Text, Text)>>`, meaning that `Content` is of type `TupleView<Text, Text>`. Looking up `TupleView`, I found it's a wrapper type originating from `SwiftUI` itself that can only be initialized by passing the tuple it should wrap.

**Question**

Now I'm wondering how in the world the two `Text` instances in this example are converted to a `TupleView<(Text, Text)>`. Is this hacked into `SwiftUI` and therefore **invalid regular Swift syntax?** `TupleView` being a `SwiftUI` type supports this assumption. Or is this **valid Swift syntax?** If yes, how can one **use it outside `SwiftUI`?**

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/3278367-init shows that there is a “custom attribute” `@ViewBuilder` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder.

Comment: Discussed in the Swift forum here https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-introduce-custom-attributes/21335 and here https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-static-custom-attributes-round-2/22938.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

[As Martin says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434549/what-enables-swiftuis-hovering-tuple-syntax#comment99463546_56434549), if you look at the documentation for [`VStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/)'s [`init(alignment:spacing:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/3278367-init), you can see that the `content:` parameter has the attribute `@ViewBuilder`:

```
init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: Length? = nil,
     @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
```

This attribute refers to the [`ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) type, which if you look at the generated interface, looks like:

```
@_functionBuilder public struct ViewBuilder {

    /// Builds an empty view from an block containing no statements, `{ }`.
    public static func buildBlock() -> EmptyView

    /// Passes a single view written as a child view (e..g, `{ Text("Hello") }`)
    /// through unmodified.
    public static func buildBlock(_ content: Content) -> Content 
      where Content : View
}
```

The `@_functionBuilder` attribute is a part of an unofficial feature called "[function builders](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md)", which has been [pitched on Swift evolution here](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-function-builders/25167), and implemented specially for the version of Swift that ships with Xcode 11, allowing it to be used in SwiftUI.

Marking a type `@_functionBuilder` allows it to be used as a custom attribute on various declarations such as functions, computed properties and, in this case, parameters of function type. Such annotated declarations use the function builder to transform blocks of code:

- For annotated functions, the block of code that gets transformed is the implementation.
- For annotated computed properties, the block of code that gets transformed is the getter.
- For annotated parameters of function type, the block of code that gets transformed is any closure expression that is passed to it (if any).

The way in which a function builder transforms code is defined by its implementation of [builder methods](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md#function-building-methods) such as `buildBlock`, which takes a set of expressions and consolidates them into a single value.

For example, `ViewBuilder` implements `buildBlock` for 1 to 10 `View` conforming parameters, consolidating multiple views into a single `TupleView`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension ViewBuilder {

    /// Passes a single view written as a child view (e..g, `{ Text("Hello") }`)
    /// through unmodified.
    public static func buildBlock<Content>(_ content: Content)
       -> Content where Content : View

    public static func buildBlock<C0, C1>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1) 
      -> TupleView<(C0, C1)> where C0 : View, C1 : View

    public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2)
      -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View

    // ...
}
```

This allows a set of view expressions within a closure passed to `VStack`'s initialiser to be transformed into a call to `buildBlock` that takes the same number of arguments. For example:

```
struct ContentView : View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text("Hello, World")
      Text("Hello World!")
    }
  }
}
```

gets transformed into a call to `buildBlock(_:_:)`:

```
struct ContentView : View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      ViewBuilder.buildBlock(Text("Hello, World"), Text("Hello World!"))
    }
  }
}
```

resulting in the [opaque result type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56433665/2976878) `some View` being satisfied by `TupleView<(Text, Text)>`.

You'll note that `ViewBuilder` only defines `buildBlock` up to 10 parameters, so if we attempt to define 11 subviews:

```
  var body: some View {
    // error: Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of
    // type 'HorizontalAlignment'
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text("Hello, World")
      Text("Hello World!")
      Text("Hello World!")
      Text("Hello World!")
      Text("Hello World!")
      Text("Hello World!")
      Text("Hello World!")
      Text("Hello World!")
      Text("Hello World!")
      Text("Hello World!")
      Text("Hello World!")
    }
  }
```

we get a compiler error, as there's no builder method to handle this block of code (note that because this feature is still a work-in-progress, the error messages around it won't be that helpful).

In reality, I don't believe people will run into this restriction all that often, for example the above example would be better served using the [`ForEach`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach) view instead:

```
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      ForEach(0 ..< 20) { i in
        Text("Hello world \(i)")
      }
    }
  }
```

If however you do need more than 10 statically defined views, you can easily workaround this restriction using the [`Group`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group) view:

```
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Group {
        Text("Hello world")
        // ...
        // up to 10 views
      }
      Group {
        Text("Hello world")
        // ...
        // up to 10 more views
      }
      // ...
    }
```

---

`ViewBuilder` also implements other function builder methods such:

```
extension ViewBuilder {
    /// Provides support for "if" statements in multi-statement closures, producing
    /// ConditionalContent for the "then" branch.
    public static func buildEither<TrueContent, FalseContent>(first: TrueContent)
      -> ConditionalContent<TrueContent, FalseContent>
           where TrueContent : View, FalseContent : View

    /// Provides support for "if-else" statements in multi-statement closures, 
    /// producing ConditionalContent for the "else" branch.
    public static func buildEither<TrueContent, FalseContent>(second: FalseContent)
      -> ConditionalContent<TrueContent, FalseContent>
           where TrueContent : View, FalseContent : View
}
```

This gives it the ability to handle if statements:

```
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      if .random() {
        Text("Hello World!")
      } else {
        Text("Goodbye World!")
      }
      Text("Something else")
    }
  }
```

which gets transformed into:

```
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      ViewBuilder.buildBlock(
        .random() ? ViewBuilder.buildEither(first: Text("Hello World!"))
                  : ViewBuilder.buildEither(second: Text("Goodbye World!")),
        Text("Something else")
      )
    }
  }
```

(emitting redundant 1-argument calls to `ViewBuilder.buildBlock` for clarity).

Comment: *`ViewBuilder` only defines `buildBlock` up to 10 parameters* – does that mean `var body: some View` cannot have more than 11 subviews?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth In reality I don't think people will run into this restriction all that often, as they'll likely want to be using something like the `ForEach` view instead. You can however use the `Group` view to workaround this restriction, I've edited my answer to show that.

Comment: Thanks for teasing this out! Did you find any support so far for reusable custom (sub-)Views/Groups, or portable/parameterized builder logic? Otherwise I can't see this as being useful (read: maintainable) for anything beyond relatively simple layouts.

Comment: @MandisaW - you can group views into your own views and reuse them. I don’t see a problem with it. I’m at WWDC right now actually, and talked with one of the engineers at the SwiftUI lab - he said that its a limitation of Swift right now, and they went with 10 as a sensible-ish number. Once variadic generic get introduced into Swift, we will be able to have as many „subviews” as we want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So from my understanding, the  `@_functionBuilder` can't have 2 functions with the same number of params. If that is true then can we get the compilation error if we make it by mistake, and if not, how it knows what functions to be used for the transformation.

Comment: Excellent info, thanks. But how come the signature of init looks different if you view it in XCode, there it has no Viewbuilder attribute: @inlinable public init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: Length? = nil, content: () -> Content)

Comment: @Gusutafu I believe that's a compiler bug – the ASTPrinter hasn't been updated yet to print attributes for parameters.

Comment: Maybe more interesting, what is the point of the buildEither methods? It seems like you need to implement both, and both have the same return type, why don't they each just return the type in question?

Comment: OK, that's a relief. It confused me quite a bit earlier today when I tried to find where the builder actually was mentioned.

Comment: @Gusutafu Good question regarding `buildEither`! I *believe* it's to help SwiftUI reason about when it needs to redraw content. For example, it [can deduce from type information whether certain views don't need redrawing](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/1135684281328553985). By using `ConditionalContent` (which `buildEither` returns), presumably SwiftUI checks whether the branch taken is the same. If so, it doesn't need to redraw as long as no other state for the view on that branch has been mutated.

Comment: Following up on my comment about the ASTPrinter bug, [this will be fixed on master once the function builders PR has been merged](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/25221/files#diff-84ee3e2e9711400bf2749d0e807a7403R2593).

Comment: Ah ok so while you always have the option to implement buildEither, the double generic one was strictly a SwiftUI thing. Maybe similar to why the return "some View", I think they prefer to have all the static knowledge about what particular View, that you would lose if you returned an existential. But your comment takes me back to my main question about SwiftUI, how the owning View can now that some State has changed. It sounds like State's storage is not on the State<T> instance, but even if it is some singleton how can the View observe it change?

Comment: Might help to refer to https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md which describes the principles in detail.

Comment: @Hamish I also have a related question: is there a way to _see_ what any given SwiftUI code got transformed into after being passed through the builder?

Comment: @matt Unfortunately, not that I know of. For the last example I did a `swiftc -dump-ast` in order to see the transformed AST, but that's pretty hard to read for non-trivial examples (and even for trivial examples, may take a little bit of knowledge about what the different nodes are for). It would be nice if sometime in the future Swift could support re-constructing readable source code from a type-checked AST, which would also let the user see things like synthesised protocol conformances.

Comment: Starting from Xcode 11.3 something has changed in implementation of ViewBuilders? My code stop working correctly.  public init<A: View, B: View, C: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> TupleView<(A, B, C)>) {
        let views = content().value
        self.childs = [AnyView(views.0), AnyView(views.1), AnyView(views.2)]
       
    }
above code no longer works, it needs to explicitly call ViewBuilder.buildBlock(), and @ViewBuilder invokes constructor for single Content view without Tuple

Answer (score 15):

An analogous thing is described in [What's New in Swift WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/402/) in the section about DSLs (starts at ~31:15). The attribute is interpreted by the compiler and translated into related code:

[image]