# How can I access modifiers of a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Assume I have a `View` with an `Image` that has a `shadow` property:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let myImage = Image("turtlerock").shadow(radius: 10)

        return myImage
    }
}
```

Now imagine I want to access the value of the shadow radius. I assumed I could do this:

```
print(myImage.shadow.radius)
```

However, this returns an error:

> Value of type '(Color, Length, Length, Length) -> _ModifiedContent<_ModifiedContent, _ShadowEffect>' (aka '(Color, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) -> _ModifiedContent<_ModifiedContent, _ShadowEffect>') has no member 'radius'

Is there a way to access the modifier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of `myImage` is:

```
_ModifiedContent<Image, _ShadowEffect>
```

We can access the original image by doing:

```
myImage.content
```

We can access the shadow effect modifier by typing:

```
myImage.modifier
```

So to do what you want, you have to type:

```
print(myImage.modifier.radius)
```

Comment: Could you please show more complete code that does work on Xcode or at least on Swift Playground for iPad?