# In SwiftUI, how can I access the current value of .foregroundColor and other modifiers inside my UIViewRepresentable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Given the following example code:

```swift
struct ActivityIndicatorView : UIViewRepresentable {
    var style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style = .medium

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicatorView>) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        return UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicatorView>) {
        uiView.color = UIColor.white // how would I set this to the current .foregroundColor value?
    }
}
```

How do I find out the current value of `.foregroundColor(…)` in order to render my UIView correctly?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506318/how-can-i-access-modifiers-of-a-view-in-swiftui) but that is from the perspective of inspecting the ModifiedContent from the outside, not the wrapped View.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to actually store this as a `@State` variable and inject it into a property you've set up inside your `UIViewRepresentable`. As is, a `View` has no such property out-of-the-box. (Even better, if you wish to "theme" your `SwiftUI` app, put the theme as part of your model to keep it centralized.)

Comment: `uiView.color` should still have the updated `foregroundColor` value, no?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access the foreground colour but you can access the colour scheme and determine the colour of your activity indicator based on that:

```
struct ActivityIndicatorView : UIViewRepresentable {

   @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme

    //...

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicatorView>) {

        switch colorScheme {
        case .dark:
            uiView.color = .white
        case .light:
            uiView.color = .black
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's disappointing. It seems like a pretty normal thing to want to know what modifiers have been applied, especially when they're such core things as element colours! Hopefully Apple will address this in a future release…

Comment: Added Apple Feedback here
https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9587930