# How do I change the background color of a Custom View like SwiftUI Views

Tags: swiftui, custom-view

I wanted my Custom views to behave like SwiftUI Views and for simplicity I'm considering the background and foreground colors. Now, instead of individually defining the foreground/background color of each subview of a view, I want to change it externally as in SwiftUI views. For simplicity, there is one subView: Text; on my tries.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestButton: View {
    var text: String
    @State private var foregroundColor: Color = .primary
    @State private var backgroundColor: Color = .white
    @State private var id = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .foregroundColor(foregroundColor )
            .padding()
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .id(id)
            .accentColor(foregroundColor)
    }

    public func foregroundColor(_ color: Color)  {
        foregroundColor = color

        id = UUID()
    }

    public func backgroundFill(_ color: Color) {
        backgroundColor = color
        id = UUID()
    }
}

struct TestButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestButton(text: "Test")
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .backgroundFill(.green)
    }
}
```

This doesn't work on Xcode 14.3 canvas, although I was expecting to work. So, I've turned into emulator to see there is a difference and the result was same as in canvas.

How can we design a Custom View so that we can use color changes as in SwiftUI's View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very interesting because of what is fairly straight-forward and what is impossible, and the very surprising dividing line between them. I'll build this up from absolutely trivial to impossible.

First, start with mapping `.foregroundColor()` to the color of the text. That is trivial and in fact requires no code at all. It "just works."

```
struct TestButton: View {
    var text: String

    // Fixed this. It should not be variable or State.
    // It needs to be constant. But it doesn't actually matter for this example
    private let id = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .padding()
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .id(id)
    }
}

struct TestButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestButton(text: "Test")
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

There's no need for any variables. The value of `.foregroundColor()` is passed directly to Text with no intervention at all. Magic!

How do you recreate that magic for `backgroundFill`? With [Environment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environment#). This is how these settings are passed down the hierarchy. First, create an environment key, and extend [EnvironmentValues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues#) to access it:

```
private struct BackgroundFillKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Color = .white
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var backgroundFill: Color {
        get { self[BackgroundFillKey.self] }
        set { self[BackgroundFillKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Then, use `@Environment` to access it:

```
struct TestButton: View {
    var text: String

    @Environment(\.backgroundFill)
    var backgroundFill: Color

    @State private var id = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .padding()
            .background(backgroundFill)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .id(id)
    }
}
```

For convenience, add an extension to View to set it:

```
extension View {
    func backgroundFill(_ color: Color) -> some View {
        environment(\.backgroundFill, color)
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
struct TestButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestButton(text: "Test")
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .backgroundFill(.green)
    }
}
```

And this is how SwiftUI manages its own Views.

But I've left out one bit of your question, which is this modifier:

```
        .accentColor(foregroundColor)
```

In your example, this doesn't actually matter. Text doesn't use `accentColor` this way. But I think you're asking a very general question, which is "how do I set `accentColor` to be `foregroundColor`?" And a little more broadly, "how do I access `foregroundColor`?"

The answer is [you don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772112/in-swiftui-how-can-i-access-the-current-value-of-foregroundcolor-and-other-mod). That environment value is marked internal. I don't know why. Here is some useful commentary: [How To Read Foreground and Tint Colors in SwiftUI Views](https://kylehugh.es/documents/how-to-read-foreground-and-tint-colors-in-swiftui-views/), and a [possible workaround/hack](https://gist.github.com/ole/7d18e9e4b656f8cc1f24c7284b493df8). But ultimately, it's not publicly available.

You can, of course, create your own `.foregroundTextButtonColor` following the above explanation of `.backgroundFill`, but it won't integrate with SwiftUI's `.foregroundColor`.

Comment: Well, the view is simplified however, the tint was there. Yes HStack carry the background to subviews. My question was a bit rather rather understanding the way of SwiftUi works.  I'm guessing that the extensions should made on the customview so that it doesn't conflict with the others, so instead of AnyView we need to return just CutomView.

Comment: I guess there is more about thin on behind the scenes of SwiftUI, since any SwiftUI view can multiple instances and each can have different colors. So, a glolabal variable ( yes I call the environment variables like this for fun) is not the real solution rather we need a namespace like solution

Comment: "I'm guessing that the extensions should made on the customview so that it doesn't conflict with the others." No, they generally need to be on View itself, or they'll be very hard to use. `.environment()` returns a new View that has the given setting for all contained views. This is not setting a global variable for all instances of CustomView. It is setting an environment for **this part of the View hierarchy** (and is not attached to CustomView; CustomView just happens to read it). It is not like the Unix environment, where there is just one.

Comment: Here's Apple's introduction to the environment in SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/216/?time=2935

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments. Yes, you are right about restriction to subviews. Still we can consider the View as a namepace. Why do we need to apply to View if it is specific to a view? It seems SwiftUI creates lots of view around by design choice.

Comment: I'm getting `Ambiguous use of 'backgroundFill` on PreviewProvider line.

Comment: SwiftUI creates lots of nested, hierarchical Views. That's a design choice. Correct. That's exactly how it's designed. I don't know what you mean here by "namespace," but I expect the answer is no. Look at how all the other modifiers are implemented. Text has a few that apply to Text and return Text (and that can bite you at times), but most modifiers apply to View return `some View`. If you want to be "like SwiftUI views" as you say, then that's how they work. If you're getting errors, I expect you have multiple `backgroundFill` extensions or didn't put it on View as I showed.

Comment: When I remove your environment definiton, I've error `Value of type 'EnvironmentValues' has no member 'backgroundFill'` so there is one around.

Comment: There should be a `backgroundFill` property extension on EnvironmentValues so that `@Environment(\.backgroundFill)` works. Separately, there should be a `func backgroundFill(_ color: Color) -> some View` as an extension on View so that `.backgroundFill(.green)` works. (This should be an extension on **View**, not **TextButton** or anything else. In order to work as written, it must be an extension on View, as most SwiftUI modifiers are.)

Comment: I don't have a `backgroundFill` around except the `Text(...). backgroundFill(...)` from standard View itself.

Comment: Okey, It conflicts with the View structs backgroundFill. So this is not possible to achive as I intended. I've changed it to `customBackgroundFill` and everything works.

Comment: SwiftUI's View doesn't have a `backgroundFill` method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view-appearance Where are finding that? Perhaps you're importing it from something else?

Comment: @Yes, you are right. I comes from SiftUIX library, sorry for confussing and fuss.

Comment: So, it turns out, we cannot override the view's modifiers since they are designed to be applied to a view from the outside.

Comment: They are not applied at all. A modifier is a View itself. It contains other Views (the modifier is the superview, not an attachment). It often sets Environment values that are seen by the Views it contains. That's why you can rarely extend a particular view with a modifier. The result of `myView.modifier(value).otherModifier(value)` is not of type `MyView`. It's going to be something like `OtherModifierContainerView<ModifierContainerView<MyView>>`. So you'd have to extend that specific huge type (that is probably internal, and is hidden behind `some View` in any case).