# How can I add a custom container view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I'm curious if you can create a custom container view within SwiftUI. I know that you can create custom content views, such as `Text()`, but wasn't sure if you could replicate the functionality of say `HStack { }`

Something akin to:

```swift
HGrid {
    Text("Lorem ipsum")
    Text("Lorem ipsum")
}
```

Where the custom container view (aka `HGrid`) would then, say, add `Spacer()` between each added component. Essentially, as an example, transpiling it to:

```swift
HStack {
    Text("Lorem ipsum")
    Spacer()
    Text("Lorem ipsum")
}
```

Comment: Possible helpful: [What enables SwiftUI's DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56434549/1187415).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SwiftUI` implements this with the `ViewBuilder` `@functionBuilder`

```swift
struct HGrid <Content: View>: View {
    init(@ViewBuilder builder: () -> Content) {
        let content = builder()
        ...
    }
}
```

See also

- https://forums.swift.org/t/function-builders/25167
- https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/pull/1046

Comment: Does it make sense to just define a property like so `let content: () -> Content` instead of this custom init?

Comment: You can do that. But than it is just a arbitrary function returning a view and not a ViewBuilder like in `HStack`.

Comment: @UgoArangino Hi, I don't understand how to create custom container as HGrid using your example? How to add spacer between each added component? How are you going to modify what you get in the builder()?

Answer (score 0):

If we try to keep it simple and do the only thing, two options can be proposed:

```
import SwiftUI
// Via custom containers
struct HGrid<Content: View>: View {
    let C1: Content
    let C2: Content

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            C1
            Spacer()
            C2
        }
    }
}
// Via View composition
struct HGridComposition: View {
    var text1: String
    var text2: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(text1)
            Spacer()
            Text(text2)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Composed from Views").font(.headline)
        HGrid(C1: Text("First"), C2: Text("Second"))
            Divider()
            Text("Composed from texts (String)").font(.headline)
        HGridComposition(text1: "Text One", text2: "Text Two")
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing])
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```