# Using @ViewBuilder to create Views which support multiple children

Tags: swift, swiftui

Some Views in SwiftUI, like VStack and HStack support having multiple views as children, like this:

```swift
VStack {
  Text("hello")
  Text("world")
}
```

From what I gather, they use [ViewBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) to make this possible as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434549/what-enables-swiftuis-dsl/56435128#56435128).

How can we use @ViewBuilder for creating our own Views which support multiple children? For example, let's say that I want to create a `Layout` View which accepts arbitrary children -- something like this:

```swift
struct Layout : View {
  let content: Some View 

  var body : some View {
    VStack {
      Text("This is a layout")
      content()
    }
  } 
}
```

Any idea how to implement this pattern in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here's an example view that does nothing, just to demonstrate how to use `@ViewBuilder`.

```swift
struct Passthrough<Content>: View where Content: View {

    let content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content()
    }

}
```

Usage:

```swift
Passthrough {
    Text("one")
    Text("two")
    Text("three")
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I don't really understand the `View where Content: View` or `@escaping` function wrapper... but this is a wonderful start.

Comment: @bento `View` protocol has an associated type, called `Body`, hence you can't say `let content: () -> View` - try it, you will get a compiler error. `@escaping` means that the closure will outlive the context (the constructor) it is in, and it does, as it is called in `body`.

Comment: Someone already answered while I was composing my answer. @escaping means that it may be performed later when the object of your custom View doesn't exist. It may cause memory leaks. So I've saved the Content as a result of the closure performed.

Comment: Here https://github.com/zhuowei/marina/blob/master/marina.swift  I found the proof that we should use var content: Content, not a var content: () -> Content. That is why Apple method don't have @escaping keyword.

Comment: @DenFav `@escaping` != `memory leaks` - In my case, I've used @escaping to provide lazy initialisation for the view body. In this example, there's no need to instantiate the children in the initialiser.

Comment: Good explanation. But I have a question. Is it possible to only show one of the subview like what TabView did? Take your example, you have 3 Text, but I only want to show only one of them at a time. That means I need to get the children of content in ViewBuilder. Is it possible?

Comment: @MatteoPacini
How can we allow multiple types instead of Text only?

Comment: I need 3 views like Button Text Button in VStack

Comment: I have a question. Is there a way to get the total number of views passed in to `Passthrough` view?

Comment: @NikzJon you could `dump` your `Passthrough` instance to get its type, e.g. `dump(type(of: view))`, and that would print something like: `Passthrough<SwiftUI.TupleView<(SwiftUI.Text, SwiftUI.Text, SwiftUI.Text)>>`. The number of generics you see inside `TupleView` are the number of views passed.

Comment: That worked. But still I need view count as a variable. i cant figure that out

Comment: @NikzJon Assuming `x` is your `Passthrough` instance, you could try `Mirror(reflecting: x.content().value).children.count` - it should return `3` for the example above.

Comment: @MatteoPacini this worked outside `Passthrough` definition. Like inside `ContentView()`, it worked fine. But I need the count of view inside init of `Passthrough` without messing with content view. This count variable help me with custom styling of views passed in to the `Passthrough`.

Answer (score 9):

Using the declaration of `VStack` we need to use `@ViewBuilder` for our content parameter. It is a closure but it **shouldn't** be @escaping it won't be good to store closure if we need only data from it. I assume that from the Apple declarations.

Also I believe that `@inlinable` is important because:

> The @inlinable attribute exports the body of a function as part of a
> module's interface, making it available to the optimizer when
> referenced from other modules.
> [More info here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0193-cross-module-inlining-and-specialization.md)

```
struct Layout <Content> : View where Content : View {
   
    var content: Content
    
    @inlinable public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is a layout")
            self.content
        }
    } 
}
```

To use it:

```
Layout {           
    Text("1")
    VStack {
        Text("1")
        Text("2")
    }
}
```

**Update:** As [Matteo Pacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2890168/matteo-pacini) noted as a misleading info about `@escaping`.

We need to use `@escaping` for `DynamicViewContent` views.
`@escaping` is used Apple's View structures for view structs that are accepting Collections(Array, Range, etc). Because the `ForEach` implements `DynamicViewContent` - a type of view that generates views from an underlying collection of data. `List` in its initializers also `ForEach` in Content

```
public init<Data, RowContent>(_ data: Data, selection: Binding<Selection>?, action: @escaping (Data.Element.IdentifiedValue) -> Void, rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element.IdentifiedValue) -> RowContent) where Content == ForEach<Data, Button<HStack<RowContent>>>, Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable
```

Comment: Re `@escaping`, Apple uses it in List, e.g. in initializer `init(_:action:rowContent:)` - another consideration is that you're creating the view structs `before` body is called. It depends on the use case, of course, but saying it must not be used could be misleading.

Comment: They are using `@escaping` in the List to provide developers an ability to create a `View` for each step of iteration. In this case we have no iterations and it is not necessary for us to store a closure in custom view. So yes, you are correct, we definitely may need `@escaping` for the Views that will receive Collections