# SwiftUI How to iterate through views passed using init of viewBuilder

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've seen in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532366/using-viewbuilder-to-create-views-which-support-multiple-children) that in SwiftUI it is possible to define a view as

```
struct Passthrough<Content>: View where Content: View {

    let content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content()
    }

}
```

And to use it as

```
Passthrough {
    Text("one")
    Text("two")
    Text("three")
}
```

`Passthrough` will just display all 3 `Text` elements without doing anything to them.

How can I "capture" each of 3 Views individually (iterate over them all) and do something to them in `Passthrough`? Let's say making each Text have different font size?

Any way I can perform `ForEach` on the elements passed to `Passthrough`?

Comment: Would like to know this as well... Seems to be impossible

Comment: Just linking the 2 questions together. This could work if [casting to `View`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59608417/4420543) worked.

Comment: linking question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238485/how-to-loop-over-viewbuilder-content-subviews-in-swiftui