# How to loop over viewbuilder content subviews in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, custom-view, viewbuilder

So I’m trying to create a view that takes viewBuilder content, loops over the views of the content and add dividers between each view and the other

```
struct BoxWithDividerView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            // here
            
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .cornerRadius(14)
    }
}
```

so where I wrote “here” I want to loop over the views of the content, if that makes sense. I’ll write a code that doesn’t work but that explains what I’m trying to achieve:

```
ForEach(content.subviews) { view  in
     view
     Divider()
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that with `ViewBuilder` - it just gives you a single view that is a composite of the underlying views. You want to keep the same DSL syntax, you'd need to implement your own `@_functionBuilder`, similar to `ViewBuilder`

Comment: do you know how to do it? I’m trying to use @_functionBuilder:
@_functionBuilder
struct UIViewFunctionBuilder {
    static func buildBlock<V: View>(_ views: [V]) -> some View {
       return ForEach(views) { view in
            view
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
But V should conform to Identifiable

Comment: There are some online [blogs](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/swift-function-builders-swiftui-view-builder/). I haven't personally done it, so I wouldn't be able to help. Maybe if you have a more specific question about implementing a `@_functionBuilder`, you could ask another question

Answer (score 8):

I just answered on another similar question, [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67243560/9607863). Any improvements to this will be made for the linked answer, so check there first.

**GitHub link of this (but more advanced) in a Swift Package [here](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor)**

However, here is the answer with the same `TupleView` extension, but different view code.

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        BoxWithDividerView {
            Text("Something 1")
            Text("Something 2")
            Text("Something 3")
            Image(systemName: "circle")  // Different view types work!
        }
    }
}
```

Your `BoxWithDividerView`:

```
struct BoxWithDividerView: View {
    let content: [AnyView]
    
    init<Views>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> TupleView<Views>) {
        self.content = content().getViews
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(content.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                if index != 0 {
                    Divider()
                }
                
                content[index]
            }
        }
//        .background(Color.black)
        .cornerRadius(14)
    }
}
```

And finally the main thing, the `TupleView` extension:

```
extension TupleView {
    var getViews: [AnyView] {
        makeArray(from: value)
    }
    
    private struct GenericView {
        let body: Any
        
        var anyView: AnyView? {
            AnyView(_fromValue: body)
        }
    }
    
    private func makeArray<Tuple>(from tuple: Tuple) -> [AnyView] {
        func convert(child: Mirror.Child) -> AnyView? {
            withUnsafeBytes(of: child.value) { ptr -> AnyView? in
                let binded = ptr.bindMemory(to: GenericView.self)
                return binded.first?.anyView
            }
        }
        
        let tupleMirror = Mirror(reflecting: tuple)
        return tupleMirror.children.compactMap(convert)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hey, I love your solution, but I wanna go one step further and generate BoxWithDividerView's children by using a ForEach. How would you go about doing that? I just end up with a bunch of protocol errors when I try doing that.

Comment: @LucasC.Feijo Check [the repo](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor). If the feature doesn’t exist there, create an issue with more detail and I’ll be sure to have a look

Comment: Isn't marking the content closure `@escaping` wrong here - it's being used in the function and not being saved to be evaluated later

Comment: @Ronnie Looks like it, though I **highly** recommend using the Swift package instead.

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up doing this

```
@_functionBuilder
struct UIViewFunctionBuilder {
    static func buildBlock<V: View>(_ view: V) -> some View {
        return view
    }
    static func buildBlock<A: View, B: View>(
        _ viewA: A,
        _ viewB: B
    ) -> some View {
        return TupleView((viewA, Divider(), viewB))
}
}
```

Then I used my function builder like this

```
struct BoxWithDividerView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    init(@UIViewFunctionBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            content()
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.AdUp.carbonGrey))
        .cornerRadius(14)
    }
}
```

But the problem is this only works for up to 2 expression views. I’m gonna post a separate question for how to be able to pass it an array

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the exact same thing. Did you ever come up with a more robust solution that will work with any number of views?

Comment: @ab1470 nope i haven’t :( let me know if you do

Answer (score 0):

Extension of Eddy's answer, using swift 5.7 and buildPartialBlock from result builders:

```
@resultBuilder
struct MyViewBuilder {
    static func buildPartialBlock<C: View>(first: C) -> TupleView<(C)> {
        TupleView(first)
    }
    
    static func buildPartialBlock<C0, C1>(accumulated: C0, next: C1) -> TupleView<(C0, Divider, C1)> where C0: View, C1: View {
        TupleView((accumulated, Divider(), next))
    }
}

struct MyView<Content: View>: View {
    @MyViewBuilder var content: Content
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView {
            Text("Text1")
            Text("Text2")
            Image(systemName: "chart.bar.fill", variableValue: 0.3)
            Text("Text3")
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is one catch with this approach: it does not allow us to treat Group as a "transparent container", i.e., a Group of two elements is not the same as two elements listed without group:

```
var body: some View {
        MyView {
            Text("Text1")
            Text("Text2")
            Group {
                Image(systemName: "chart.bar.fill", variableValue: 0.3) // no Divider() between image and text
                Text("Text3")
            }
        }
    }
```

If we unite last 2 elements into one Group, divider between them disappears.

The only way to make it work correctly with Group I found is described here: https://movingparts.io/variadic-views-in-swiftui