# What is the difference between List and ForEach in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I know SwiftUI does not support currently regular for loops but instead provide something called ForEach but what is the difference between that and a List?

Comment: Maybe this post can help you figure it out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434549/what-enables-swiftuis-dsl

Comment: ForEach and List are both containers.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

- `ForEach` is a view that lets you pass a collection of data to its initializer and then creates multiple "subviews" from the closure you provide. It doesn't have any semantics on how the views will be arranged.

  #### Example:

  ```
    ForEach(1..<5) { row in
        Text("Row \(row)")
    }
  ```

  will create the equivalent off

  ```
    Text("Row 1")
    Text("Row 2")
    Text("Row 3")
    Text("Row 4")
  ```

  wrapped in a single container view.
- `List` is a view that can compose multiple views together, but not necessarily views of the same type. You can simply add multiple views without any loop.

  #### Example 1:

  ```
    List {
        Image("avatar")
        Text("Title")
        Button(action: {
            print("Button tapped!")
        }) {
            Text("Energize!")
        }
    }
  ```

  As a *convenience*, the `List` initializer allows you to use it just like the `ForEach` view in case you want to have a list consisting of a single cell type only.

  #### Example 2:

  ```
    List(1..<5) { row in
        Text("Row \(row)")
    }
  ```

  A list has a special appearance, depending on the platform. For example, on iOS a list will appear as a table view and insert separator lines between its vertically stacked views.

  You can use `ForEach` views inside `List` views to have both dynamic and static content – a very powerful feature of *SwiftUI*.

  #### Example 3:

  ```
    List {
        Text("Food")
        ForEach(meals) { meal in
            Text(meal.name)
        }
        Text("Drinks")
        ForEach(drinks) { drink in
            Text(drink.name)
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: Nice answer. Some tweaks: 1. You don’t need most of those `return`s ([SE-255](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md), yo). And if you’re just passing a string to `Text(...)` there’s no need to wrap it in string interpolation — SwiftUI automatically makes programmatic Strings non localized and localizes literals and interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Updated my answer accordingly. Looks much nicer!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the performance? Which one does reusing cells better? For a continuous feed kind of data set, which one should be preferred?

Comment: I (sadly) realized that a ForEach (without List) can't manage insert, update and delete animations. Of couse you can add an animation and transition modifier to your rows, but sadly they also get fired when you just update a row (this leads to an insert animation when you e.g. just updated the text at one index). In a list this also triggers as "new row" (onAppear() gets triggered) but the list itself manages to suppress animation ...

Comment: "Example" doesn't work anymore in 2021, pls change to `ForEach(1..<10) { row in`

Comment: Thanks, updated accordingly. ✅

Answer (score 14):

**SwiftUI List vs ForEach**

`List`:

- mixed content(also allows to work with collection)
- scrollable
- uses reusing cell pattern (efficient)

`ForEach`:

- works only with a collection

`List` + `ForEach` = super feature. In this case, for example, `List` uses reusing cell pattern for every view from `ForEach`. Also you are able to use `onMove`, `onDelete`...

Answer (score 9):

**Simple explanation:**

- **List** behaves kind of like a **UITableView** (where each of the elements gets a cell view, and it's also scrollable).
- **ForEach** behaves like a **for-loop** of views; it unrolls a collection of views but adds *no* additional behavior.

  - It's often used inside of a **UIScrollView** to add scrolling
  - and/or an HStack or VStack to control layout direction.

Comment: This is a useful way to equate it back to UIKit, for users coming from the old way. Minor quibble, but I think it's the other way around: List behaves like UITableView, and ForEach behaves like UIScrollView. I tested both, and ForEach by itself just displays repeating Text views, whereas List shows cells with borders.

Comment: It's a good answer though. It helped me since I'm used to the UIKit way.

Comment: ForEach is not scrollable tho

Comment: corrected the explanation given the above feedback