# ForEach inside of List, VStack and LazyVStack in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I came to **SwiftUI** from **UIKit** world and wondered how lists work in **SwiftUI**.
This topic is a continuation of [the topic about ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535326/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-foreach-in-swiftui/66224651#66224651).

The question is how to make sure that the list of elements is effective in terms of memory management and speed.

So I came up with two different implementations:

1. List of cells based on `List`:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(0..<469) { i in
        MyCellView(num: i)
            .frame(height: 40)
    }
}
```

2. List of cells based on `VStack`:

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        ForEach(0..<469) { i in
            MyCellView(num: i)
                .frame(height: 40)
        }
    }
}
```

3. List of cells based on `LazyVStack`:

```swift
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(0..<469) { i in
            MyCellView(num: i)
                .frame(height: 40)
        }
    }
}
```

Seems like `ForEach` acts like a generator which supply the parent view with new items.
In the example 2 with `VStack`, the memory graph shows a lot of pre-defined structures (as expected 469 in my case):

[image: VStack with ForEach in SwiftUI]

Does it means that they are pre-rendered or just structures in memory?

In opposite to 2, examples 1 and 3 are requesting only the number of cells which is displayed on the screen.

But still, the main questions is how to make sure that **SwiftUI** reuses the cells as `UITableView` did and avoid memory overflow?

Comment: In LazyVStack there is Lazy : that means the system try to render only the needed views (which are structs). The List seems to act quite the same (even if not directly stated as this in doc ) The VStack will need to render all its contents.