# Using state variables as inputs to a func in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two text fields that change the value of two @State variables, namely startingMileage and endingMileage, and a stepper that changes the value of a third @State variable named fuelAdded.  I'm trying to use the user's inputs and do a calculation to calculate miles per gallon. In playground, my code works as expected. It does not work in a SwiftUI project, however.

Tried running the code in playground as below:

```swift
func CalcMPG(start: String, end: String, fuel: Double) -> Int {
    let start = Int(start) ?? 1
    let end = Int(end) ?? 1
    let fuel = Int(fuel)
    let mpg = (end-start) / fuel
    return mpg
}


var endingMileage:String = "9250"
var startingMileage:String = "9000"
var fuelAdded:Double = 20

let milesPerGallon = CalcMPG(start: startingMileage, end: endingMileage, fuel: fuelAdded)
print("Fuel Efficiency: \(milesPerGallon) mpg")
```

This works as expected.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var startingMileage: String = ""
    @State var endingMileage: String = ""
    @State var fuelAdded: Double = 10
    @State var carModel: String = ""
    @State var showMPGInfo = false
    @State var milesPerGallon: Int = 10

    func CalcMPG(start: String, end: String, fuel: Double) -> Int {
        let start = Int(start) ?? 1
        let end = Int(end) ?? 1
        let fuel = Int(fuel)
        let mpg = (end-start) / fuel
        return mpg
    }


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                HStack {
                    Text("Car Model:")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField($carModel, placeholder: Text("Toyota Corolla"))
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Starting ODO:")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField($startingMileage, placeholder: Text("8000"))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    Text("miles")
                }

                HStack {
                    Text("Ending ODO:")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField($endingMileage, placeholder: Text("9000"))
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    Text("miles")
                }
                HStack {
                    Stepper(value: $fuelAdded, in: 0...20, step: 0.5) {
                        Text("Fuel Added: \(fuelAdded, specifier: "%0.1f") gallons")
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.showMPGInfo.toggle() }){
                        Text("Show/Hide MPG")
                }
                    if showMPGInfo {
                        Spacer()
                        milesPerGallon = CalcMPG(start: startingMileage, end: endingMileage, fuel: fuelAdded)
                        Text("Fuel effiency: \(milesPerGallon) MPG")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }.padding()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Gas Mileage Calculator"))
        }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on "Show/Hide MPG". I expect the end resulting text to be "Fuel Efficiency: xx MPG"

However, I get the following errors:

ContentView.swift:34:19: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

It doesn't appear anywhere sensical to me... It highlights the starting VStack in the NavigationView.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Okay, it must be something to do with the declaration of: `milesPerGallon = CalcMPG(...) ` because as soon as I take that out and just put \(CalcMPG(...)) into the text I want to return it works as desired. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Is it not right to use a @State var in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the assignment to `milesPerGallon` does not work well with the “function builder syntax” used to build the arguments of the view hierarchy. It becomes a bit more obvious if we replace `@State var milesPerGallon` by a local variable (which is *is,* it does not carry state on which the view depends, only a intermediate value):

```
if showMPGInfo {
    Spacer()
    let milesPerGallon = CalcMPG(start: startingMileage,
                                 end: endingMileage, fuel: fuelAdded)
    Text("Fuel effiency: \(milesPerGallon) MPG")
        .font(.largeTitle)
}
```

Now the compiler error is

```
Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'
```

For more information about the function builder syntax see [What enables SwiftUI's DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434549/what-enables-swiftuis-dsl) (which has also links to the documentation).

The simplest solution would be to avoid a local variable and interpolate the text directly:

```
if showMPGInfo {
    Spacer()
    Text("Fuel effiency: \(CalcMPG(start: startingMileage, end: endingMileage, fuel: fuelAdded)) MPG")
        .font(.largeTitle)
}
```

Other solutions are to calculate the text field in an “immediately evaluated closure”:

```
if showMPGInfo {
    Spacer();
    { () -> Text in
        let milesPerGallon = CalcMPG(start: startingMileage,
                                      end: endingMileage,
                                      fuel: fuelAdded)
        return Text("Fuel effiency: \(milesPerGallon) MPG")
    }()
    .font(.largeTitle)
}
```

or to define an auxiliary function

```
func resultField(start: String, end: String, fuel: Double) -> Text {
    let  milesPerGallon = CalcMPG(start: startingMileage, end: endingMileage, fuel: fuelAdded)
    return Text("Fuel effiency: \(milesPerGallon) MPG")
}
```

and use it as

```
if showMPGInfo {
    Spacer()
    resultField(start: startingMileage, end: endingMileage,
                fuel: fuelAdded)
        .font(.largeTitle)
}
```

There may be other workarounds, but that is what I came up with so far.