# How to scroll to position UIScrollView in Wrapper for SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uikit

i have a ScrollView from UIKit and use it for SwiftUI: [Is there any way to make a paged ScrollView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893240/is-there-any-way-to-make-a-paged-scrollview-in-swiftui)

**Question:** How can I scroll in the UIScrollView to a position with a button click on a button in a SwiftUI View OR what is also good for my needs to scroll to a position when first displaying the ScrollView

I tried contentOffset but this didnt work. Perhaps I've done something wrong.

**ScrollViewWrapper:**

```
class UIScrollViewViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.isPagingEnabled = false
        v.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        return v
    }()

    var hostingController: UIHostingController<AnyView> = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.pinEdges(of: self.scrollView, to: self.view)

        self.hostingController.willMove(toParent: self)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.hostingController.view)
        self.pinEdges(of: self.hostingController.view, to: self.scrollView)
        self.hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)

    }

    func pinEdges(of viewA: UIView, to viewB: UIView) {
        viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewB.addConstraints([
        viewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.leadingAnchor),
        viewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.trailingAnchor),
        viewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.topAnchor),
        viewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }

}

struct UIScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIScrollViewViewController {
        let vc = UIScrollViewViewController()
        vc.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIScrollViewViewController, context: Context) {
        viewController.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
    }
}
```

**SwiftUI usage:**

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @ObservedObject var search = SearchBar()
    var body: some View{
       NavigationView{
        GeometryReader{geo in
            UIScrollViewWrapper{      //<-----------------
                VStack{
                    ForEach(0..<10){i in
                        Text("lskdfj")
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geo.size.width)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Test")
        }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why UIKit version? there is SwiftUI version.

Comment: There are bugs if having the Scrollview inside a navigationview with the title. Sometimes it’s jumping.

Comment: I have used ScrollView in NavigationView and its has title. it does not jump.

Comment: Use UITableView instead of UISscrollView.

Comment: What I mean is something like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64280447/scrollview-navigationview-animation-glitch-swiftui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will first declare the `offset` property in the `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, with the propertyWrapper `@Binding`, because its value can be changed by the `scrollview` or by the parent view (the `ContentView`).

```
struct UIScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var content: () -> Content
    @Binding var offset: CGPoint
    init(offset: Binding<CGPoint>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        _offset = offset
    }
// ....//
}
```

If the offset changes cause of the parent view, we must apply these changes to the `scrollView` in the `updateUIViewController` function (which is called when the state of the view changes) :

```
func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIScrollViewViewController, context: Context) {
    viewController.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(content())
    viewController.scrollView.contentOffset = offset
}
```

When the offset changes because the user scrolls, we must reflect this change on our `Binding`. To do this we must declare a `Coordinator`, which will be a `UIScrollViewDelegate`, and modify the offset in its `scrollViewDidScroll` function :

```
class Controller: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var parent: UIScrollViewWrapper<Content>
    init(parent: UIScrollViewWrapper<Content>) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        parent.offset = scrollView.contentOffset
    }
}
```

and, in `struct UIScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable`

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Controller {
    return Controller(parent: self)
}
```

Finally, for the initial offset (**this is important otherwise your starting offset will always be 0**), this happens in the `makeUIViewController`:
you have to add these lines:

```
vc.view.layoutIfNeeded ()
vc.scrollView.contentOffset = offset
```

The final project :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200)
    let texts: [String] = (1...100).map {_ in String.random(length: Int.random(in: 6...20))}
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                UIScrollViewWrapper(offset: $offset) { //
                    VStack {
                        Text("Start")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        ForEach(texts, id: \.self) { text in
                            Text(text)
                        }
                    }
                        .padding(.top, 40)
                    
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Test")
                
            }
            HStack {
                Text(offset.debugDescription)
                Button("add") {
                    offset.y += 100
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.white)
        }
    }
}

class UIScrollViewViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.isPagingEnabled = false
        v.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        return v
    }()

    var hostingController: UIHostingController<AnyView> = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        pinEdges(of: scrollView, to: view)

        hostingController.willMove(toParent: self)
        scrollView.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        pinEdges(of: hostingController.view, to: scrollView)
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func pinEdges(of viewA: UIView, to viewB: UIView) {
        viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewB.addConstraints([
            viewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.leadingAnchor),
            viewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.trailingAnchor),
            viewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.topAnchor),
            viewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

struct UIScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var content: () -> Content
    @Binding var offset: CGPoint
    init(offset: Binding<CGPoint>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        _offset = offset
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Controller {
        return Controller(parent: self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIScrollViewViewController {
        let vc = UIScrollViewViewController()
        vc.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        vc.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(content())
        vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        vc.scrollView.contentOffset = offset
        vc.scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIScrollViewViewController, context: Context) {
        viewController.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(content())
        viewController.scrollView.contentOffset = offset
    }

    class Controller: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var parent: UIScrollViewWrapper<Content>
        init(parent: UIScrollViewWrapper<Content>) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            parent.offset = scrollView.contentOffset
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well this works fine with static data but when the data is dynamic i.e, coming from API, The scrollView is unable to resize to correct height.
when I get more data I see last data size for scrollView.

Comment: You have to update the scrollview content size in `updateUIViewController`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass a `@Binding var offset: CGPoint` into the `UIScrollViewWrapper` then when the button is clicked in your SwiftUI view, you can update the binding value which can then be used in the update method for `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. Another idea is to use `UIViewRepresentable` instead and use that with `UIScrollView`. Here is a helpful article doing that and setting its offset: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/scrollview-offset/.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first approach and it worked. In my first try I have bound the binding through the controller to the other controller which didnt work

Comment: I want that the scrollview starts at some specific point. I don't know how to do it. Sometimes the scrollview updates the position and sometimes not. How is the right handling of the variables? If I perhaps let the contentOffset be a value of y: 100 in the makeUIController there is no offset on the screen