# SwiftUI Stuttering/Flickering of UIScrollView position when scrolling to top

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI 3.0 `ScrollView`, when I tap the status bar to scroll to top, the scroll animation suffers from stuttering/ flickering... this is a recording of a slowdown animation, showing the problem.

Problem Demonstrationn

[image: scrolling stuttering]

This is the fruit details View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FruitDetailsView: View {
    
    var fruit: Fruit
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                        
                        FruitsHeaderView(fruit: fruit)
                            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                            .cornerRadius(16)
                        
                        Text(fruit.title)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(fruit.gradientColors[1])
                        
                        Text(fruit.headline)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        
                        Text("Learn more about \(fruit.title)".uppercased())
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(fruit.gradientColors[1])
                        
                        Text(fruit.description)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 640, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, -1.0)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(fruit.title, displayMode: .automatic)
    }
    
}

struct FruitDetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FruitDetailsView(fruit: fruitsData[0])
    }
}
```

this is the FruitsHeaderView...

```
import SwiftUI

struct FruitsHeaderView: View {
    
    var fruit: Fruit
    
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: fruit.gradientColors), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
            
            Image(fruit.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.15), radius: 8, x: 6, y: 8)
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
        }
        .frame(minHeight: 200)
        .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fill)

    }
}

struct FruitsHeaderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FruitsHeaderView(fruit: fruitsData[0])
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 375, height: 440))
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find the solutions?

Comment: I used some alternative back then, didn't find a direct solution.

Comment: May this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64280447/scrollview-navigationview-animation-glitch-swiftui solves your problem