# What exactly does creating a Form in swiftUI does mean?

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, closures, swiftui

```
var body: some View {
    Form{
        Text("Hello, World")
    }
}
```

At this code, what this code

```
 Form{ Text("Hello, World") }
```

means? Is this creating an instance of the 'Struct Form'? or is it creating an instance of 'Struct Form' and just adding a closure? or do I have to just call it function builder?

Comment: Are you asking about how does the weird-looking syntax you use in SwiftUI work?

Comment: [What enables SwiftUI's DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56434549/1187415) – is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, Kind of, I know how using From affects View but I got no idea what that weird-looking one exactly is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is calling of `Form` constructor

> ```
> /// A container for grouping controls used for data entry, such as in settings
> /// or inspectors.
> ///
> /// - SeeAlso: `Section`, which can be used to add sections between groups of
> ///     content.
> @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> public struct Form<Content> : View where Content : View {
>
>     public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
> ```

so

```
Form{ Text("Hello, World") }
```

is equivalent of

```
Form.init(content: { () -> Text in
    return Text("Hello, World") 
})
```