# Why does two views but no container compile?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
        Text("World")
    }
}
```

The preview shows the first text field but not the second. They'll both appear if they're contained in a stack.

```
var f: Bool {
   true
   false
}
```

This results in the compiler complaining about a missing return in function - a single bool value is ok.

So, why are two views ok but not two bools? Is it a quirk of the view builder?

Comment: `View` is an element of SwiftUI and uses a special DSL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434549/what-enables-swiftuis-dsl

Comment: Yes, it is an effect of ViewBuilder. Btw, you have rather two previews, just scroll canvas down.