# Own VStack in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create my own simplified implementation of VStack in SwiftUI without using any default containers. I understand that I need to use @ViewBuilder to pass views through a closures. But I cant understand how to get access to passed views to somehow iterate over them to calculate and set position of each passed view.

```
struct MyVStack<Content: View>: View {
    var content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
       self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        viewsCollection = GetCollectionFrom(content()) // ???
        ForEach(viewsCollection) { view in
           // Calculate and set new positions of each view
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

I feel what I'm thinking in a right direction but doing something wrong.

Comment: You need to do the same to what ViewBuilder does. This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/65986943/12299030.

Comment: Thanks! So I need to override all init functions I guess

Comment: @Corban_Dallas See this repo: https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor