# SwiftUI doesn't like switch?

Tags: swift, if-statement, switch-statement, swiftui

Trying to following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517610/conditionally-use-view-in-swiftui), I implemented the suggestion of [Yurii Kotov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11873221/yurii-kotov):

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var index = 0

@ViewBuilder
 var body: some View {
   if index == 0 {
       MainView()
   } else {
       LoginView()
   }
}
```

It works fine. But if I try to use a switch statement instead:

```
    switch  index {
        case 0: MainView()
        case 1: LoginView()
        default:
            print("# error in switch")
        }
```

nothing happens. There is no mistake alert, but also no result at all. Could somebody help?

Comment: Your switch statement does not do the same thing as the if. If you write an equivalent switch statement, then it should work.

Comment: OK, Sweeper, but what is wrong with it?

Comment: Think about the case when `index`  is 2. What will the if do? What will the switch do?

Comment: It s an interesting discussion, but I have defined index as 0, so it should be not interesting for switch what happens by 1000. It should match the 0 case. IMHO.

Comment: Whenever a `@State` changes, your view updates, which means that everything in `body` is evaluated again.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't think your code would compile in the first place...

Comment: As  said, I got the positive result, using the if-statement. But what to do, if you have more cases and more views in play?

Comment: After reading the other answers in your linked post. It appears that the `ViewBuilder` function builder turns if statements into `_ConditionalContent`s, which is strictly a "either this or that" thing. You would have to nest if statements to achieve more cases. But if your true intention is to have more cases, you better use `AnyView`. See Mike Glukhov's answer.

Comment: Thank a lot for your time. I will check other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sweeper said: your `if...else` and `switch...case` statements are not equal. The main idea is: `body` is just a *computed variable* of a [View protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view) and it **should return** something of its' type. Sure, you can do it with `switch...case` statements. In your code snippet mistake is in `default` statement: **body cannot return`() -> Void`**, only `some View`. So your code should looks like this:

```swift
struct ViewWithSwitchStatements: View {

    @State var option = 0

    var body: some View {

        switch option {
        case 1:
            return AnyView(Text("Option 1"))
        case 2:
            return AnyView(Text("Option 2"))
        default:
            return AnyView(Text("Wrong option!"))
        }

    }
}
```

However you can't put it into `VStack` or something else, like `if...else` statements.

Comment: Also, be careful and avoid returning Opaque types from ViewBuilders (don't wrap in AnyView) as it hides all the type information and compiler cannot optimise so well.

Answer (score 8):

I had an issue with the default case where I wanted a "break" type situation for the switch to be exhaustive.  SwiftUI requires some type of view, I found that

`EmptyView()` solved the issue.

also noted here [EmptyView Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60988527/displaying-an-empty-view-in-swiftui) that you "have to return something"

```
struct FigureListMenuItems: View {
    var showContextType: ShowContextEnum
    @Binding var isFavoriteSeries: Bool?

    var body: some View {
    
        Menu {
            switch showContextType {
            case .series:
                Button(action: { toggleFavoriteSeries() }) {
                    isFavoriteSeries! ?
                    Label("Favorite Series?", systemImage: "star.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    :
                    Label("Favorite Series?", systemImage: "star")
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                }
            default: // <-- can use EmptyView() in this default too if you want
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("No menu items")
                }
            }
        } label: {
            switch showContextType {
            case .series:
                isFavoriteSeries! ?
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                :
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
            Label("Menu", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle")
        }
    }

    private func toggleFavoriteSeries() {
        isFavoriteSeries?.toggle()
    }
}
```

Enum for switch

```
enum ShowContextEnum: Int {
    case series = 1
    case whatIsNew = 2
    case allFigures = 3
}
```