# Displaying an empty view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

In SwiftUI there's frequently a need to display an "empty" view based on some condition, e.g.:

```swift
struct OptionalText: View {
  let text: String?

  var body: some View {
    guard let text = text else { return }

    return Text(text) 
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile since the body of `guard` has to return some view, that is an "empty" view when `text` is `nil`. How should this example be rewritten so that it compiles and renders an "empty" view when `text` is `nil`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`@ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder). Then you don't even need an `EmptyView`:

```
@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    if let text = text {
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

Note that here you use `@ViewBuilder` to just *build* your view. If you want to learn more about how it's done behind the scenes, please see the below answer:

- [What enables SwiftUI's DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56434549/8697793)

Comment: A pedantic note but you absolutely are "returning" something, the function has a delcared return type. The fact you don't have to explicitly `return` something is actually a result of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md. The SwiftUI DSL and `@ViewBuilder` make the building of views a single statement. </pedantic>

Comment: @Procrastin8 Yes, I'm aware of it, what I meant was that we don't return anything *directly*, ie. using the *return* keyword. But your explanation might be clearer for future readers.

Comment: I would love to understand _why_ this works. You have a variable that must return an opaque type, but you only return it under some conditions. Does @ViewBuilder cause it to return `EmptyView` by default?

Comment: @ChristopherPickslay The best explantion you can find here: [What enables SwiftUI's DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56434549/8697793).

Answer (score 35):

You have to return something. If there is some condition where you want to display nothing, "display" an...`EmptyView` ;)

```swift
var body: some View {
    Group {
        if text != nil {
            Text(text!)
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

The SwiftUI DSL will require you to wrap the if/else in a `Group` and the DSL has no guard/if let nomenclature.

Answer (score 18):

As of Xcode 12 beta 2 the `Group` view is no longer needed and `if let` declarations are supported, so the resulting `body` can be a bit more succint:

```swift
var body: some View {
    if let text = text {
        Text(text)
    } else {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually now you can just leave off the `else ` entirely. `EmptyView` is automatically the else condition in case the `if` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the shortest version of your code (`if let` shorthand declared for Swift 5.7+) that you can use in Xcode 14.0 and higher. This kind of `optional binding` shadows an existing variable.

```
struct ContentView: View {       
    @State var text: String? = nil

    var body: some View {   
        if let text {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

If you choose to use the `guard let` shorthand statement, implement this version:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text: String? = nil

    var body: some View {
        nonOptionalText(text)
    }
    
    func nonOptionalText(_ text: String?) -> some View {
        guard let text else { return Text("") }
        return Text(text)
    }
}
```