# SwiftUI ForEach with index - "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time"

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach, swift-compiler

In a swiftUI view that I'm writing, I need to use a `ForEach`, accessing each element of a list *and* its index. Most of the information I could find about this said to use `.enumerated()` as in `ForEach(Array(values.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, value in }`

However when I try to do that in my view:

```
/// A popover displaing a list of items.
struct ListPopover: View {
    // MARK: Properties
    /// The array of vales to display.
    var values: [String]
    
    /// Whether there are more values than the limit and they are concatenated.
    var valuesConcatenated: Bool = false
    
    /// A closure that is called when the button next to a row is pressed.
    var action: ((_ index: Int) -> Void)?
    /// The SF symbol on the button in each row.
    var actionSymbolName: String?
    
    // MARK: Initializers
    init(values: [String], limit: Int = 10) {
        if values.count > limit {
            self.values = values.suffix(limit - 1) + ["\(values.count - (limit - 1)) more..."]
            valuesConcatenated = true

        } else {
            self.values = values
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Body
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(values.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, value in
                HStack {
                    if !(index == values.indices.last && valuesConcatenated) {
                        Text("\(index).")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }

                    Text(value)
                    
                    Spacer()

                    if action != nil && !(index == values.indices.last && valuesConcatenated) {
                        Spacer()

                        Button {
                            action!(index)
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: actionSymbolName ?? "questionmark")
                        }
                        .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                    }
                }
                .if((values.count - index) % 2 == 0) { view in
                    view.background(
                        Color(.systemGray5)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions` on the line `var body: some View {`

I've also noticed that this code causes some other problems like making the Xcode autocomplete extremely slow.

Any ideas how I might be able to solve this? It seems like a pretty simple view and I think I'm doing the `ForEach` how I should.

Thanks!

Comment: Not reproducible for me on 12.5 or 13.0b4. In the past, I've noticed that Xcode sometimes has a problem with boolean evaluation with `&&` in SwiftUI, so I'd consider building helper functions for those that can be split out.

Comment: Do **not** use `id` as `\.offset` - use `\.element` instead. Using offset causes issues when the elements change.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very misleading error. What it really means is you screwed something up in your `body`, but the compiler can't figure out the error, so it throws it on the `body` itself. The easiest way to find it is to comment out portions of your `body` in matched braces until the error goes away. In your case the issue is with this:

```
            .if((values.count - index) % 2 == 0) { view in
                view.background(
                    Color(.systemGray5)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                )
            }
```

I am not sure what you are attempting to do, but `.if` is not valid syntax and I am not sure what `view` is or where it is supposed to come from.

Comment: I would bet that the OP is using something like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57685253/560942) which is a common extension in SwiftUI

Comment: Yeah that’s correct about `.if`, I should have mentioned in my post. I have tried commenting out different parts of it and I can get the code to compile, however even if I remove everything but the `ForEach`, Xcode is still extremely slow.

Comment: This is why you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I didn't have any issue with the ForEach. Now that I added that extension, it is building for me. Therefore, I would try the standbys: Clean the Build Folder, and delete your DerivedData folder.

Comment: 12.5.1 I think? Whatever the newest non-beta version is.

Comment: have you cleaned the build folder and deleted the DerivedData for the project?

Comment: I just got home and was able to try that, it didn’t seem to make any difference.

Comment: I think @jnpdx was right about the && logic being the problem. I moved each row into its own view and that didn’t help, but it made me realize that removing the code `!(index == values.indices.last && valuesConcatenated)` made it work. I also noticed that I forgot to unwrap `.last`, but doing that still didn’t fix it.