# Switch TextFieldStyle between OS

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, textfieldstyle

Say I have 2 TextFieldStyles like below where one of them should run with iOS 15+ if available.

```
struct TF1: TextFieldStyle {
    init()
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {}
}
```

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct TF2: TextFieldStyle {
    @FocusState var focused: Bool
    
    init()
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {}
}
```

Now I want to use theses style with modifier `.textFieldStyle()` where I pass in the right style.

For example

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    TextField("").textFieldStyle(TF2())
} else {
    TextField("").textFieldStyle(TF1())
}
```

Above code **works** but can be improved. Is there a way to write an adapter so I can just do something like below?

```
   TextField("").textFieldStyle(Adapter())
```

Comment: put that conditional code inside `_body` and you'll have one style

Comment: I need to have 2 styles since the one with iOS15 use the wrapper `@FocusState` and we can't declare like

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
@FocusState var focused: Bool
```

Comment: You can use an [.if modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517610/conditionally-use-view-in-swiftui/57685253#57685253) to achieve your goals and conditionally apply the appropriate `textFieldStyle` to your `TextField`