# Can I create a generic ObservableObject class which can be used by multiple ContentViews?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11, combine

Hi I was just wondering is it possible to create a generic class confirming to ObservableObject protocol which can be used by more then one ContentViews.

If i can do that then I will be able make my ContentView and Model class completely generic and reusable.

An example of what i would like to achieve:

```
protocol ContentViewModelType: ObservableObject {
    var propertyToInitialiseView: [String] { get }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: some ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

If I can do that any class can implement ContentViewModelType and become a model for ContentView which makes it generic and reusable. For example

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewModel, Never>()
}
```

But when i try to initialise ContentView that xcode gives me a type error.

[image]

I thought the whole point of introducing some keyword was so that we can use protocol as type for those protocols that have associated type as a requirement and hence this should work. But it gives an error.

If anyone has any references or knowledge about this problem that they could share or possibly a solution for this it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `protocol ContentViewModelType: ObservableObject`... correct me, but you cannot do this - `ObservableObject` is *always* a `class` object.

Comment: `dfd` it's fine for a protocol to inherit from another protocol. It just means "this protocol requires all the things of my ancestor, and also…" You're correct that `ContentViewModelType` doesn't *conform* to `ObservableObject`. Unfortunately "inherits from" and "conforms to" are spelt identically in Swift.

Comment: This technique is demonstrated in WWDC 2020 Structure your app for SwiftUI previews from 21:13 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10149/?time=1273

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to understand your question, and I am not quite sure I understand the intent... but to create a view which takes in generic view model (based on the protocol you had before) you will need the following code:

```swift
protocol ViewModelWithProperties: ObservableObject {
    var properties: [String] { get }
}

struct SomeView<T>: View where T: ViewModelWithProperties {
// this can also be written as 
// struct SomeView<T: ViewModelWithProperties>: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: T

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(item.properties, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To consume this instance you will need to:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SomeView(item: MyViewModel())
    }
}
```

As stated in one of the other answers, `some` is used for opaque types, it doesn't make your code generic.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much. Why didn't it cross my mind to make the view struct generic.

Comment: Glad you find it useful.

Comment: Life saving answer! Spot on!

Comment: This does not seem to work if the ContentView has an init () method, can you help please?

Comment: How can I use it for a different protocol type say NewViewModelWithProperties

Answer (score 3):

This is not what `some` is for. `some` creates an opaque return type, not an existential ("any") type. [See the docs for more detail.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html) See also [What is the `some` keyword in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433665/what-is-the-some-keyword-in-swiftui/57365095)

A `some` type must be a single type, known at compile time. It's just not known to the caller. What you're trying to do is pass an existential, which is a type known at *runtime*. Nothing has changed in Swift 5.1 about existentials. You would still need to wrap this up in an `AnyContentViewModel` if that's what you wanted. (I'll need to think a bit on whether that would be a good idea or not.)

But the code as you've written it also doesn't do what you're describing. You're not actually using `ContentViewModelType` anywhere. Did you mean `some ContentViewModelType`? That still won't work, but it seems what you mean.

Answer (score -2):

If I'm understanding you correctly you could do something like this:

You could have a an ObservableObject class as follows:

```
import Foundation

class SampleTimer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var timerVar: Int = 0

    init(){
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){
            timer in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.timerVar += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sampleTimer = SampleTimer()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(sampleTimer.timerVar)")
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(sampleTimer: sampleTimer) ){
                    Text("Go to second view")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a SecondView like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sampleTimer : SampleTimer
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(sampleTimer.timerVar)")
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing that I wanted to outline was that if you have a timer like I do and it's initialized in the `init()` function AND you create a new instance of `SampleTimer()` in the `SecondView` (i.e. `@ObservedObject var sampleTimer = SampleTimer()` instead of what I have) instead of getting the same instance passed down from the `ContentView()` to the `SecondView()` you will have two different instances of  `SampleTimer` meaning that the values will not be the same in the `ContentView` and the `SecondView`