# Creating WebView using SwiftUI 2.0 can't create a view from UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying create a WebView view in SwiftUI 2.0 Xcode 12.4 but it's so new I can't find good examples for answers and best practice.  For the code below I get the following error.

Type 'SwiftUIWebView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'

Also setting the config has changed and I can't enable .allowsContentJavaScript properly.  Trying to add it to the "perfs" triggers an error complaining about not liking a Bool.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct SwiftUIWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL?
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some WKWebView {
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)   //frame CGRect
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let myURL = url else { return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `some` from this line:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some WKWebView {
```

`some` is a specific keyword used when dealing with generics and opaque types (see this link for more reading: [What is the `some` keyword in Swift(UI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433665/what-is-the-some-keyword-in-swiftui)). In this case, you don't need to generic-ize `WKWebView`, since you know exactly what it is.

You can set the `prefs.allowsContentJavaScript` property by doing this:

```
prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
```

Comment: Here is what worked in the end.  Getting rid of the "some" and it rejected adding this to perfs so did this way and it works:

```
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)   //frame CGRect
    }
```