# Memory-related crash caused by the "some" keyword in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm getting `Global buffer overflow` crashes when I define SwiftUI view's with the `some View` type. The crashes go away when I use the exact types.

This crashes: `let txt: some View = Text("Hi")`

This works: `let txt: Text = Text("Hi")`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the use case of trying to name it with `some View`? `

Comment: I've have an app that has a few custom buttons, texts, images, etc that are used multiple times. I'm simple defining these elements in a separate file it's in this file where the crashes happen. If I create a file that just have `import SwiftUI` and `let txt: some View = Text("Hi")`, its crashes when I try to use `txt` somewhere else.

Comment: But why define it as `some View` and not just `Text`?

Comment: Because I need to define more complex reusable components where the methods used to customize the component returns `some View` instead of the actual concrete type. For example, `let txt: Text = Text("Hi").frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)` doesn't compile because frame has the return type of `some View`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it might be something like that. It just sounds like fighting the compiler to me. Will post a possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opaque types don't *seem* to be made for definitions like this. There's a lot of interesting information about this on this SO thread: [What is the `some` keyword in Swift(UI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433665/what-is-the-some-keyword-in-swiftui)

You can type the variable as `AnyView` and use `AnyView()` to wrap/type erase the content -- then you can use any modifiers you want.

```
let txt: AnyView = AnyView(Text("Hi").frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center))
```

I particularly like this extension to make it look a little cleaner:

```
extension View {
    func eraseToAnyView() -> AnyView {
        return AnyView(self)
    }
}

let txt: AnyView = Text("Hi").frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center).eraseToAnyView()
```