# How can I assign value of some View to type View in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple View called **TextView**, the type of **TextView** is naturally **View**, I want make a modification on **TextView** like **.foregroundColor(Color.red)** and replace it again as itself! from my understanding my **TextView** is type View and should just working because the type is not **Text** But also I understand the complaining from SwiftUI which says cannot assign value of **some View** to type **View**. I like make some correction for solving issue, also I am not interested to add another initializer as **foregroundColor**.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
   @State private var myTextView: TextView?
    
    var body: some View {

        if let unwrappedMyTextView = myTextView {
            
            unwrappedMyTextView
            
        }
        
        Button ("update") {
            
            myTextView = TextView(stringOfText: "Hello, world!")//.foregroundColor(Color.red)
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct TextView: View {

    let stringOfText: String
    
    init(stringOfText: String) {
        self.stringOfText = stringOfText
    }

    var body: some View {

        return Text(stringOfText)
        
    }
 
}
```

[image]

Comment: why not use it like this? ```if let unwrappedMyTextView = myTextView {
            unwrappedMyTextView.foregroundColor(Color.red)
        }```

Comment: thanks, yes there is lots of ways, my point is replacing or updating, not exactly given red foregroundColor

Comment: Then you can add a condition in the color function. it's not a good way to replace whole view with @State.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `foregroundColor` doesn't return `TextView`:

```
@inlinable public func foregroundColor(_ color: Color?) -> some View
```

Which means that

```
myTextView = TextView(stringOfText: "Hello, world!").foregroundColor(Color.red)
```

is no longer a `TextView` but some other View which is a result of applying `foregroundColor`.

Also, you shouldn't hold `View` properties as `@State`.

Try this instead:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        myTextView
    }
    
    var myTextView: some View {
        TextView(stringOfText: "Hello, world!")
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly you pointed the right thing **func foregroundColor** returns **some View** with your code modification happening inside  myTextView, which I would like it happens in **body**, my all point is replacing **TextView** with **some View**

Comment: @swiftPunk *my all point is replacing TextView with some View* - then you can use `var myTextView: some View` as proposed above. Or is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: so you are using **TextView** to make  **myTextView**, which I think you are transforming **View** to **some View** right? that is the way you found, and I have nothing against it, unless as you can see my original question was about making some kind of correction to my code that **TextView** type became **some View**, and after that correction I could easily modify a value of type **TextView** say: giving **foregroundColor** and then assign again to the same value which you can see in my code. I mean updating the Value type TextView that is what I am trying learn.

Comment: @swiftPunk We don't transform anything here - that's the point. Any struct that conforms to View is already *some View* - whether you want it or not :) First I suggest you read [Opaque Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html) and [What is the `some` keyword in Swift(UI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56433665/8697793).

Comment: I was thinking the same that Any struct that conforms to View is already some View, and I got xcode error of **Cannot assign value of type`some View to type TextView`** because TextView has View type and as you said conforms to some View, then It should just working, but did not worked, I already explained in my question about View and some View. I think for SwiftUI View and some View are different things

Comment: @swiftPunk But `some View` is not a usual type, it's an opaque type. It behaves differently. Again, please read the links I posted before, they're the key to understand the difference between some View and View.