# Swift: returning a runtime random opaque type generates an error

Tags: swift, type-mismatch, mismatch, opaque-types

I am learning opaque types now, still a bit confusing. I tried the following:

```
protocol Animal {
    func introduce()
}

struct Dog: Animal {
    func introduce() {
        print("Dog")
    }
}

struct Cat: Animal {
    func introduce() {
        print("Cat")
    }
}

func random() -> some Animal {
    let value = [true, false].randomElement()!
    return value ? Cat() : Dog()
}
```

And in the return line of `random` I am getting the following error

`Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'Cat' and 'Dog'`

So, as far as I understand just like Generics the compiler needs to be able to decide at compile time what the concrete return type of the function is.

Am I right? If I am, isn't this message about confusing as both structs implement `Animal`? And if I'm wrong, what does this error message mean?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: I'm trying to understand, not to make it work :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433665/what-is-the-some-keyword-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this: What is the type of the expression value ? Cat() : Dog()
It isn’t animal. And for a ternary you need one type but you have either a cat or a dog. Type inference isn’t going to figure out that you can erase those two different types back to some common type, even if it’s possible to do so

Comment: But If I remove `some` it compiles. Is it because in this case swift returns an existential container and not a concrete type?

Comment: @Yotam read the question linked in the comment above

Comment: Yes If you return an Animal that means it can infer animal for the ternary expression. Both things can be the same then, the ternary is happy. But that’s not the case for some animal because that means you’re returning an actual cat, say, or an actual dog. The caller can take it to be some animal, but that’s downstream. Some animal is not a type, so that can’t unify the two ternary types.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I did, wasn't clear enough. Anyway I think I got it. Thanks