# Type specific method is unavailable for a var returned with `some` directive

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, factory-method

Consider a factory method pattern implementation:

```
import UIKit

protocol TransportProtocol: CustomStringConvertible {
    func techReview()
}
// Make default implemetation opposed to @objc optional methods and properties
extension TransportProtocol {
    func techReview() {
        print("Reviewing \(type(of: self))")
    }
    var description: String {
        "This is a \(type(of: self))"
    }
}

final class Car: TransportProtocol {
    func changeOil() {
        print("Changed oil")
    }
}

final class Ship: TransportProtocol {
}


protocol LogisticProtocol {
    associatedtype Transport: TransportProtocol
    func createTransport() -> Transport
    func delivery(from A: Any, to B: Any)
    func techRewiew(for transport: TransportProtocol)
}

extension LogisticProtocol {
    
    func delivery(from A: Any, to B: Any) {
        print("Moving \(type(of: self)) from \(A) to \(B)")
    }
    
    func techRewiew(for transport: TransportProtocol) {
        transport.techReview()
    }
}

final class RoadLogistics: LogisticProtocol {
    
    func createTransport() -> some TransportProtocol {
        Car()
    }
    
}

final class SeaLogistics: LogisticProtocol {
    
    func createTransport() -> some TransportProtocol {
        Ship()
    }
}

// Usage:

class Client {
    // ...
    static func someClientCode<L: LogisticProtocol>(creator: L) -> some TransportProtocol {
        let transport = creator.createTransport()
        print("I'm not aware of the creator's type, but it still works.\n"
              + transport.description + "\n")
        creator.delivery(from: "Source", to: "Destination")
        return transport
    }
    // ...
}

              
let someTransport = Client.someClientCode(creator: RoadLogistics())
type(of: someTransport.self) // Car
someTransport.changeOil() // Error: Value of type 'some TransportProtocol' has no member 'changeOil'
```

The question is why I can't call `changeOil()` on `someTransport` if the compiler knows it is a `Car` not just a `TransportProtocol`.
Are there any benefits we can get from using `some` directive, not just bare protocol types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of the method is `some TransportProtocol`, not `Car`. So even though the returned instance is of type `Car`, you cannot call any methods on it that only exist on `Car`, but not on `TransportProtocol`.

The **runtime** knows that the concrete type of `someTransport` is `Car`, but the **compiler** only knows that the return type conforms to `TransportProtocol`.

If you want to be able to access `Car` methods on `someTransport`, you need to downcast it to `Car`.

```
if let car = someTransport as? Car {
    car.changeOil()
}
```

Using the `some` keyword has type-system benefits when used for opaque returns types (introduced in [SE-0244](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md) as part of Swift 5.1), since it actually enables returning a protocol with associated types without having to explicitly make the method generic. This is what drives SwiftUI, since it enables you to return `some View`.

On the other hand, using opaque return types for protocols without associated types holds no benefits, so in your particular example, there's no reason to use it.

Comment: This is so, but I could do a downcasting with from a bare protocol type as well and go without `some` directive.

Comment: @PaulB Check my updates answer.

Comment: Interesting changes are coming in SE-0335. Returning a protocol with associated types without having to explicitly make the method generic is a saver in many situations along with other benefits mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56433885

Comment: @PaulB yes, however, none of those apply to your particular example, since your protocol does not have any associated type requirements, so it can be used on its own as a return type, no need to make the method generic

Comment: The sample is a bit artificial and can be written without generics (actually it was at the beginning) but IRL protocols with associated type requirements are widespread. So your answer and comments were rather helpful for me.