# Question about using Self keyword and opaque return type Some in protocol extensions

Tags: swift

I am beginning to learn some Swift at the moment and I have been following the 100 Days of Swift on Hacking with Swift (Day 13). I have a question about using the Self keyword.

```
extension Numeric {
    func squared() -> Self {
        self * self
    }
}
```

In the above section of code, the author notes that to add the protocol extension to have squared functionality we can use the Self keyword so that the specific type (i.e. int, double) of the calling Numeric type is referenced. However, I was wondering could we just replace `Self` with `some Numeric` instead? Would that also accomplish the same task because the compiler could figure out what exact type was being referenced in this instance when `squared()` is called? What is the difference between these calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I was wondering could we just replace `Self` with `some Numeric` instead?

Yes, but only in the sense that the extension itself will still compile. The compiler can indeed see that `self * self` is an expression of type `Self`, and `Self` trivially conforms to  `Numeric`, and so can be returned in a method returning `some Numeric`.

However, callers of `squared` will probably break, and that is where the difference is.

The idea of `some` is that callers *don't* know what the actual type returned is. If you were returning `Self`, the caller has the guarantee that `x.squared()` is the same type as `x`. But with `some Numeric`, the caller only knows that `squared` returns a type conforming to `Numeric`, but doesn't know which specific type it is.

This means that it is possible to implement `squared` like this (not that this makes any sense):

```
extension Numeric { 
    func squared() -> some Numeric { 
        Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    } 
}
```

After all, `timeIntervalSince1970` returns `TimeInterval`. which is also `Numeric`.

Example:

```
func doSomethingWithInts(_ x: Int) { ... }

let x = 2
let y = x.squared() // if squared returns "some Numeric"...
print(y.bitWidth) // this is not allowed
doSomethingWithInts(y) // nor is this
```

After all. `squared` could be implemented to return any specific `Numeric`-conforming type, not necessarily the same type as `x`. What if it returned `TimeInterval`? There is no `bitWidth` there.

If `squared` returned `Self` on the other hand, then the caller knows that `y` is `Int`, for the reason that `x` is `Int`, and you can do all those things shown above that you were not allowed to do.

Note that although the caller doesn't know what specific type `some Numeric` is, it does know that it is *the same type every time*. For example, this works:

```
let a = 2
let b = 3
var x = a.squared() // calling squared on Int returns "some Numeric"
// the Numeric type returned by the call below is the same type as a.squared()
// because b is also Int, so the assignment is allowed
x = b.squared() 
print(x)
```

This is a bit off-topic, but the above is what differentiates `some Numeric` and `any Numeric`.

Read more about `some` [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56433665/5133585).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `some Numeric`, but it's a weaker guarentee:

```
extension Numeric {
    func squared() -> some Numeric {
      // Just a dummy implementation, ignore the details
      // The opaque return type is always an `Int`, regardless of `Self`.
      123
    }
}

let iThoughtThisWouldBeADouble = 2.0.squared()

print(type(of: iThoughtThisWouldBeADouble)) // Surprise, it's an Int.
```

In this example, `squared()` *can* return the same type as `self`, but it's not obligated to, as shown. `Self` (`Double` in this example) is just one example that satisfies `some Numeric`, but any other Numeric-conforming type (like `Int`) can also fit.