# Returning a custom GeneratorType

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a Class which should provide a random generator based on a collection.
Since it is a random generator (next() will never return nil, unless the collection was empty), I don't want to be able to use this generator as a sequenceType (NO 'for in' support to avoid infinite loop)

I can't seems to get the method signature right.

Here is a skeleton of what I've build, I've include 3 tries with their corresponding compiler errors.

```
public protocol myProtocol {
  var name : String { get }
}

internal struct myProtocolStruct: myProtocol {
  let name : String
  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

internal struct myGenerator : GeneratorType {
  let names : [myProtocol]

  init(names: [myProtocol]) {
    self.names = names
  }

  mutating func next() -> myProtocol? {
    return names.first
  }
}

public class myClass {

  private var items : [myProtocol]
  public init() {
    let names = ["0", "1", "2"]
    items = names.map{ myProtocolStruct(name: $0) }
  }

  public func generate0() -> GeneratorType { //  error: protocol 'GeneratorType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
    let x = myGenerator(names: items)
    return x
  }
  public func generate1<C: GeneratorType where C.Element == myProtocol>() -> C {
    let x = myGenerator(names: items)
    return x    //  error: 'myGenerator' is not convertible to 'C'
  }
  public func generate2<C: GeneratorType where C.Element: myProtocol>() -> C {
    let x = myGenerator(names: items)
    return x    //  error: 'myGenerator' is not convertible to 'C'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GeneratorOf`:

```
/// A type-erased generator.
///
/// The generator for `SequenceOf<T>`.  Forwards operations to an
/// arbitrary underlying generator with the same `Element` type,
/// hiding the specifics of the underlying generator type.
///
/// See also: `SequenceOf<T>`.
struct GeneratorOf<T> : GeneratorType, SequenceType { ... }
```

`GeneratorOf` can be created from another generator (which need
not be public):

```
public func generate() -> GeneratorOf<myProtocol> {
    return GeneratorOf(myGenerator(names: items))
}
```

`GeneratorOf` can also be created directly from a closure which represents the `next()` function:

```
public func generate() -> GeneratorOf<myProtocol> {
    var genItems = self.items // capture the items for use in the closure
    return GeneratorOf {
        // Return next element, this is just an example which
        // returns and removes the first element from the array:
        return genItems.count > 0 ? genItems.removeAtIndex(0) : nil
    }
}
```

If you want to return a generator that does *not* conform to
`SequenceType` then you could define a slight modification of the wrappers defined in
[How is a type-erased generic wrapper implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832498/how-is-a-type-erased-generic-wrapper-implemented):

```
public struct GeneratorOnlyOf<T> : GeneratorType {

    private let _next:() -> T?

    init(_ nextElement: () -> T?) {
        _next = nextElement
    }

    init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == T>(var _ base: G) {
        _next = { base.next() }
    }

    public mutating func next() -> T? {
        return _next()
    }
}
```

and then replace `GeneratorOf` by `GeneratorOnlyOf`:

```
public func generate() -> GeneratorOnlyOf<myProtocol> {
    return GeneratorOnlyOf(myGenerator(names: items))
}
```

Or you can (as you already indicated in a comment) define your own
*non-generic* protocol:

```
public protocol MyProtocolGenerator {
    mutating func next() -> myProtocol?
}
```

make your internal generator conform to that protocol:

```
internal struct myGenerator : MyProtocolGenerator { ... }
```

and then return that from the `generate()` method:

```
public class myClass {

    // ...
    public func generate() -> MyProtocolGenerator {
        return myGenerator(names: items)
    }
}
```

---

(Old answer:) The `generate()` method returns the concrete generator type, not
the protocol:

```
func generate() -> myGenerator {
    let x = myGenerator(names: items)
    return x
}
```

Compare the generators of the built-in Swift types, for example

```
struct Array<T> : MutableCollectionType, Sliceable {
    // ...
    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<[T]>
    // ...
}
```

or

```
struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value> : CollectionType, DictionaryLiteralConvertible {
    // ...
    func generate() -> DictionaryGenerator<Key, Value>
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I want my concrete struct to be internal to 1 framework, and use the method from an other one. So I can't (and don't want) to expose my concrete struct. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks, I had rejected that option because GeneratorOf is also a SequenceType, which is the thing I don't want to be. (no 'for in' support) I think I will need to go with adding a custom protocol that implement next() -> MyProtocol and use that protocol directly for the return type.